# exercise in differential calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ be a map defined by $f(x,y)=(x+a\sin y,y+b\sin x)$ with $a$ and $b$ are two positive reals such that $ab<1$.

1- Prove that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is a diffeomorphism.

2- Prove that $f(\mathbb{R^2})=\mathbb{R^2}$.

Can any one help me in question 2?

Comment: Question 2 is a part of Question 1, since a diffeomorphism must be (1) injective, (2) surjective, (3) differentiable, and (4) have differentiable inverse,

Comment: What's an application? Also, what have you tried? @SammyBlack part 1 says that $f$ is surjective on to its image which is true by definition, and does not imply part 2.

Comment: @Daniel: application is french for "map".

Comment: application = map. So can you help me please. How we resolve this question please

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what the author of the exercise had in mind, but here is a topological proof.

Consider the grid formed by the points $(2k\pi, y)$ and $(x,2h\pi)$, with $k,h$ integers, and $x,y$ real numbers. Its image under $f$ is a grid with curved lines, let's call it $X$. Suppose there exist a point $P\notin f(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Note that $P$ is located inside one of the cell of the grid $X$, i.e. inside of a deformed circle $C$, which is the image under $f$ of a square $Q$. Consider the composition $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow f(\mathbb{R}^2)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{P\}$. The induced map on the fundamental groups is $f_* : \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{P\})$, i.e., $f_*: 0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. But $f_*([Q])=[C]$, so $f(0)=1$ which is absurd.

Following the request of the OP, here is a more brutal solution.

Let $A,B$ be real numbers. We have to solve the system of equations $f(x,y)=(A,B)$. From the first equation we deduce $\sin y=(A-x)/a$. The second equation implies that $y=B-b\sin x$ hence $\sin y=\sin (B-b\sin x)$. Finally plugging in our first expression, we are reduced to find the solutions of:
$$(A-x)/a=\sin (B-b\sin x)$$
i.e.
$$g(x):= x+a\sin (B-b\sin x)-A=0$$
Since $a\sin (B-b\sin x)-A$ is bounded, $g(x)>0$ for $x$ sufficiently large and $g(x)<0$ for $x$ sufficiently small. By continuity of $g$ we deduce that there exists a root, $x'$. Take $x=x'$ and $y=B-b\sin x'$.

Comment: But how we can prouve it with differential calcul?